# How to construct different-type-ones-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have two tables: A (id, ... some other columns) and B (id, ... some other columns). I need to associate Comments (another table: id, text, author) with A and B objects.

Can I do something like creating the fourth table for that purpose: comment_id, table_id (A or B or maybe others), item_id? I mean some sqlalchemy way?

Now I know only of those two solutions:
http://bpaste.net/show/27149/ - for each A and B there will be separate table with comments. I don't think it's a good idea, because those tables are (should be) identical, if I want to see all comments by some author - it will be more difficult than the other ways, if there will be C table someday - I will need to create a table for its comments...

Another solution - http://bpaste.net/show/27148/. I think is better, but I still will be needing to create an association table for every table I need to comment the items.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), nullable=True)
    text = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
```

It is still a relatively hacky way to do it, but it preserves referential integrity by using foreign keys.

If you'd like to go for the solution where you store the table name, you could try something like this:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'as'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode, nullable=False, unique=True)
    comments = relationship("Comment",
                    primaryjoin="and_(A.id==Comment.id, "
                        "Comment.model=='A')")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    model = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
```

I have not tested this myself, so if you run into problems have a look at [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) or comment and I will do more research.

For an in-depth explanation of the subject, see [Mike Bayer's blog entry on Polymorphic Associations](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2007/05/29/polymorphic-associations-with-sqlalchemy/)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I think the first way will work, but it's no good, imho: there will be too many unused columns for every comment (there will be not only A and B, but many more). The second one is ok, I guess, but not as good as using table ids and item ids. I'm not actually sure that it is implemented in sqlalchemy though.

Comment: @kishkin I added a link to an in-depth discussion of the topic by SQLalchemy's creator

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the second solution too. But, as you say there might be a third table `C`, then you could put the `B_Comment` and `A_Comment` as fields in one single association table, like:

```
class Comment(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('as.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bs.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    text = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    # ...
```

And you would use a query like: `session.query(Comment).filter_by(a=whatever)`

I guess you could add some kind of a constraint so that `a_id` and `b_id` are not simultaneously `NULL` ?

Here's another way to do it (I don't know if it's the *standard* way to do it, but it should work...

```
class Letter(Base):
    id = ...

class A(Base):
    letter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('letters.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    # ...

class Comment(Base):
    letter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('letters.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea, there will be many unused columns for every comment. Or is it ok actually?

Comment: @kishkin I think you are right, but it's still better than having many unused **tables**. I will add another way, that might fit better your case.

Comment: Kinda like one id stack for everything?

Comment: @kishkin yes, and Comment links to the "Base" of `A` and `B`. I once read it was used as a good alternative to soft delete, but it might fit with what you want...

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll try implementing one of the solutions and see which is simpler to use.